# cant show the results of query in php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello I am new at `php` and `mysql` and I don't know what is wrong.

I cant show the results from query and the connection with `mysql` is successfully connected.

I don't use `wampserver` I just install `php`,`mysql` and `Apache` separately.

Thanks in advance.

**Code**

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";


$sql="select * from `books`;";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
if (!$result){
     echo "query cannot execute";
};

?>
```

its only show me  "query cannot execute"

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: please remove ; from query like $sql = "select * from `books`";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass fourth parameter `database name` in **[mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)**

It would be

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,"YOUR_DATABASE");
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to check error in query.

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
To fetch data from query result

Comment: thank you so much i saw it and i think its not so necessary you are my hero